# Unsupported operation: Cannot clear an unmodifiable list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page on which groups of masters are displayed. Masters are grouped by specialty. I also have a deadline for finding a specific master. When I enter the master's name in this term, only the group in which this master is included should remain. It used to do that, but recently an error appeared.
Error:Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot clear an unmodifiable list.

My code :

[image]

error in line :
element.masters.clear();
element.masters.addAll(searchedItems);

masterlist:

```html
            [
            {
                group: "group car ",
                groupid: "2447d85a-f128-11ec-8104-0cc47ab327b9",
                masters: [
                    {
                         master: "Andrii Lyis",
                         code: "700",
                         id: "a93b0e67-fb6e-11ec-8104-0cc47ab327b9",
                         rating: 4,
                         responses: 1
                    },
                    {
                         master: "Alex Pul",
                         code: "701",
                         id: "b523601a-7d35-11ed-8132-0cc47ab327b9",
                         rating: 0,
                         responses: 0
                    }
                 ]
               },
                           {
                group: "group house ",
                groupid: "2347d85a-f128-11ec-8104-0cc47ab327b9",
                masters: [
                    {
                         master: "Sem Huer",
                         code: "702",
                         id: "a83b0e67-fb6e-11ec-8104-0cc47ab327b9",
                         rating: 4,
                         responses: 1
                    },
                    {
                         master: "Karl Icus",
                         code: "709",
                         id: "b323601a-7d35-11ed-8132-0cc47ab327b9",
                         rating: 0,
                         responses: 0
                    }
                 ]
               }
               
             ]
```

My bloc
[image]
maybe someone knows how to solve?

Comment: can you share declaration of masters list

Comment: Isn't your masters list declared as const?

Comment: @HitarthChhunchha i add list master

Comment: Or isn't your masters list default value is a const [] in the element's constructor? Because you are filtering searchedData's empty masters lists.

Comment: @CsabaGergely I add image with my bloc? What should I do in this case?

Comment: @CsabaGergely thanks, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This constructor solves your problem. In this case you won't work with constant list, that's why you can add, or clear it anytime.

```
  MoreMasterMastersState({
     this.inProgress = true,
     List<RatingsMasterListModel>? paramListMasters,
     this.searchQuery = '',
     List<RatingsMasterListModel>? paramSearchedData,
   })  : listMasters = paramListMasters ?? [],
         searchedData = paramSearchedData ?? [];
```

Comment: thanks, but do I understand correctly that instead of "List<String>?" there should be "List<RatingsMasterListModel>?" ??

Comment: if so, then the error has not disappeared, unfortunately

Comment: Hmm. This is strange. I created a gist which using List<String>, where it works like charm. [LINK HERE](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8802560c0bffce0acc7d4a8bab8c2f1f)